# How to specify the style of just one header in an Ag-Grid?

Tags: css, header, ag-grid-angular

I would like to specify the Header style of just one column on my grid! I know how to configure the Header style for all columns of a specific grid. For that it's necessary to add on "styles.scss" file the following:

Example:

```
#IdOfGrid .ag-header-cell-label {
justify-content: left;}
```

How can I apply this style for just one column header?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share link or code of your page so that i can provide better solution.   

Right now, By checking you code you have added i can just say that your code will style all with this class `.ag-header-cell-label`.  

So you can add one more different class to that column or by using Pseudo-classes style it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a CSS class in `headerClass` property inside columnDefs like this:

```
columnDefs = [
{
  headerName: "Table Name",
  headerClass: "table-header",
  field: "tableName"
},
 .
 .
 .
]
```

In css, use `::ng-deep` along with another component/class names if your ag-grid-angular component is wrapped inside different elements. In my case, I got the style like this:

```
::ng-deep .main-wrapper app-custom-grid ag-grid-angular .table-header {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

You can add headerClass property to your column properties and add css for that class it applies only for that column header

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are right, in fact I can apply a style using the  headerClass property. However I'm trying to align the Title to the left and I don't find any way to do it. It's a CSS problem I'm quite sure, but if you have any suggestion it would be very welcome!

Comment: How to provide dynamic style via script? css classes are static, so they can't accept parameterized values for background-color

Answer (score 0):

To set column basic style, just give:

```
headerName: 'Title Here',
field:'title',
styleCss: { background: '#eee'; 'font-size': '15px' }
```

If you want to give style on some condition, then you need a external func, and call it inside column definition, as follows:

```
constructor(){
  this.gridOptions = {

    getRowStyle: (params: any) => {
      if (params.data){
        if(params.data.flag) {
          return { background: '#eee', 'font-weight': 750 };
        }
      }
    }
  }// end of gridoptions
}// end of constructor
```

For more detail, look deeply on my another answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236065/7118138